# Parse config file and return query results: Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have function of the form:

```
conf = conf("filename", overrides=[])
```

I need to return config object. this function will be called at boot time. 
ini file has the following format:

```
[section1]
key1=value1
key2=value2
[section2]
key3=value3
key4=value4
```

Below is my code that parses the file and store the data into a hash called 'config'.

```
#filename config.rb
require './IniFile.rb'

obj = IniFile.new
obj.write()
#config hash stores the key-value pair of the ini file
config = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = Hash.new}
config = obj.to_h()
#parses the command from the terminal
a = gets.chomp
b = a.split(".")
c = b[1]
d = b[2]
```

Here c & d are the key to query the hash. I am trying run the ruby code in the backend so that the user with only write command in the terminal like

```
>>config.section1.key1
```

output should be value1

```
>>config.section2.key4
```

output should be value4

At this time my code needs to be run every single time user wants to search a query. How can I run my code in backend once to implement this functionality?
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TwP/inifile/master/lib/inifile.rb this is the link for inifile.rb

I want to start config.rb once and fire queries in the command prompt without running the same code multiple times.

Comment: Please include a *lot* more information.  What's your backend?  Show the code, please.  Exactly what needs to be retrieved from the config file, and from where?  Show the code, please.  How does the client interact with the backend application?  Show the code, please.  We can't answer an architecture or design question without any information about your existing architecture.  You can click the `edit` button below your Question (directly above these comments) to post all of the additional information.

Comment: The `conf = conf...` construct is odd.  Even if this works, it's not a good idea to use a legitimate method name as a local variable name; it hides the method from that point onward in its scope.

Comment: You have 2 consecutive assignments to `config`.  The 2nd overrides the 1st.  It's a good idea to clean up this kind of stuff before posting a question -- you save the people helping you from having to waste time and energy understanding something that is not relevant to your question.

Comment: Are you using `inifile` gem for reading INI files? If so, you should say so. Do you need to change its behaviour? Or just to use it, but you want to load the INI contents in some particular data structure?